# tiff lzw compression 10 times larger than the original jpeg compression

Tags: image, compression, imagemagick

i converted a few jpeg compressed files into tiff lzw compression but to my surprise their sizes were larger than the original jpeg ones. I checked the format of the converted files using imagemagick's identify tool and found that they were using LZW compression.

What could be the reason behind this? Any one having a idea ?

i also tried it using faststone image converter and still with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is entirely expected and normal.  JPEG is a lossy conversion that allows significant compression by accepting some degradation in the image.  TIFF LZW compression is lossless, and so by definition cannot change the image at all for the purposes of compression, greatly limiting how far it can get.  Furthermore, LZW is not a particularly good compression scheme, even for lossless.  There are better ones.  The most common is PNG, but there are better ones depending on the type of image, such as JBIG for bilevel or images or JPEG 2000 lossless for natural images.